# Nginx + apache + wordpress example.com/wp-admin redirects to example.com:8080/wp-admin

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, wordpress

I have Nginx running on port 443 working as reverse proxy for apache on port 8080, apache handles php files for wordpress. I've setup wordpress and everything works fine except of wp-admin. When I put https://example.com/wp-admin in my browser it redirects me to example.com:8080/wp-admin. How do I fix it?

```
server {
listen              443 ssl http2 default_server;
server_name         example.com;
set                 $base /home/www/example.com;
root                /home/www/example.com/public;

# SSL
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;
access_log          /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
error_log           /var/log/nginx/example.error.log warn;
# security
include             snippets/security.conf;
# additional wordpress config
include             snippets/wordpress.conf;
include             snippets/performance.conf;
server_name_in_redirect off;
index index.php;
location / {
    try_files $uri @apache;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location @apache { # used by location /
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
```

}

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue - can you add your nginx config to your post? Also, why utilize nginx AND Apache instead of just one of them?

Comment: If I remeber correctly there is an option in the admin dashboard to set the public domain. From there you can change it from example.com:8080 to example.com.

Comment: @tilleyc this is a common setup, using nginx for Load-Balancing and Caching, apache for the Application as it has the most knowledge on the developer site. So its not unusual, but what i see is, that his question seems to be private and not being a business related question

Comment: I've added my nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the site root URL properly in WordPress. For example, in `wp-config.php`, add the following:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
```